# Finding the height of a child based on the parents input

Tags: java, height

I've been trying to make a program in java to compute the height of a child based on the parents height in feet/inches, ans to estimate that answer based on the gender that the user input. I've been stumped on this for hours though. Seems like nothing I try is doing the right calculations.

Added a pic of how my program should look when it's done.

[(( Example of how the output needs to look. ))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwoax.jpg)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
String userChoice;
int heightMom, heightDad, FemaleChildh, MaleChildh, genderChild;
    
System.out.println("Enter the gender of your future child. Use 1 for female, 
0 for male.");
genderChild = scan.nextInt();
    
System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then the height in inches of 
the mom.");
heightMom = scan.nextInt();
    
System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then the height in inches of 
the dad.");
heightDad = scan.nextInt();
    
MaleChildh = (heightMom*13/12 + heightDad)/2;
FemaleChildh = (heightDad+12/13 + heightMom)/2;
    
if (genderChild.equals(1))
System.out.println(("Your future child is estimated to grow 
to")+FemaleChildh);
   
if (genderChild.equals(0))
System.out.println(("Your future child is estimaed to grow to")+MaleChildh);
            
System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to run again, anything else to exit.");
userChoice = scan.next();
if (userChoice.equals("Y"))
System.out.println("Continuing...");
else if (userChoice.equals(""))
break;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting -how do you know it is not working properly? This will help narrow down the issue. Also include your sample inputs/expected outputs to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate heightmom and heightdad into feet and inches.
Use doubles to store your MaleChildh and FemaleChildh.
Fix the typo with the word 'estimaed'.

EDIT: See if you understand this code, then add the inch part to the child's height.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userChoice;
    int heightMomFt, heightMomIn, heightDadFt, heightDadIn, genderChild;
    double FemaleChildhFt, MaleChildhFt, FemaleChildhIn, MaleChildhIn;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the gender of your future child. Use 1 for female, 0 for male.");
        genderChild = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then the height in inches of the mom.");
        heightMomFt = scan.nextInt();
        heightMomIn = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then the height in inches of the dad.");
        heightDadFt = scan.nextInt();
        heightDadIn = scan.nextInt();

        MaleChildhFt = (heightMomFt * 13 / 12 + heightDadFt) / 2;
        FemaleChildhFt = (heightDadFt + 12 / 13 + heightMomFt) / 2;

        if (genderChild == 1)
            System.out.println(("Your future child is estimated to grow to") + FemaleChildhFt);

        if (genderChild == 0)
            System.out.println(("Your future child is estimated to grow to") + MaleChildhFt);

        System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to run again, anything else to exit.");
        userChoice = scan.next();
        if (userChoice.equals("Y"))
            System.out.println("Continuing...");
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate them into secondary inputs from the user?

Comment: Yeah, like heightMomFt and heightMomIn, heightDadFt and heightDadIn.

Comment: Would we need to calculate the estimated inches for the child with a similar calculation that we did for the feet, and then add that to the output?

Comment: Yes, but then you also have to account for inch to feet conversion. If my answer helped you, please accept and upvote it.